# Is there a cross-platform header in the standard library that provides access to the current time?

Tags: c++, time, cross-platform, standard-library

Probably a stupid question, but I couldn't find anything searching...

Is there a standard header that allows me to fetch the current time? Otherwise is there some cross-platform alternative?

Comment: I added the C++ tag. I assume that's the language you're asking about (but you never actually mention it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[time.h](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/time.h.html), and the [time](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/time.html) function.

Answer (score 5):

What's wrong with `<ctime>` ?! It's standard, even [MSDN admits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb6xk0y1(VS.80).aspx):

Comment: So is ctime portable? Like does it ship with the standard library? Or what?

Answer (score 2):

use boost date_time. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html.

Comment: The current time can be fetched using <ctime>.